# Disable administrator rights on an old work PC running Windows 10

Tags: administrator

I need to remove the ability to have to have the administrator for updating my HP PC running Windows 10.

I recently lost my job due to COVID-19 and as a result they allowed me to keep my computer.

I need to remove software and updates now that it’s mine but I can’t do this due to administrative rights. Is there a way around this? It’s my PC now and not working for the company I should be able to use it as is.

Edit: Everyone says contact the employer that is NOT an option so I need options on how I can do this. Or what I need to do to remove this.

Comment: If you are just a standard user on this computer, there is not much way to change it. You can try Pogo Stick to see if you can change the password of the local administrator account (if there even is a local admin account).   https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/  . Otherwise call the Company and ask them to log in and set you up properly.

Comment: Yea that's not going to happen. So is re formatting my only option?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact your former employer and ask them about this.

Comment: Yea that's not going to happen it's not possible so what are my options here?

Comment: If the company was large and the license for Windows was a Volume License, you need to purchase a Windows 10 License to format. If the company was small and OEM Windows was installed, you can reinstall Windows and it will pick up the license from the Microsoft Licensing server.

Answer (score 0):

This way will only work if you log in with a local account instead of Microsoft account.

First, you have to make a bootable USB from a linux ISO. Then boot from it and after booting mount the windows partition. Then open a terminal and type `sudo file_manager_name`. Then go the System32 directory of windows. Rename osk.exe to osk1.exe and cmd.exe to osk.exe. Then reboot into windows. At login screen click on screen keyboard. Then you will get a elevated command prompt. Use net localgroup Administrators "username" /add`. Then you will be the adminstrator.

But if you log on with a Microsoft account, then the only way is you ask your employer or reinstall windows 10 to gain Administrator rights.

Comment: sucks that the company is not there so can't do that it's just not possible.